# WebSocketSubject not working

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I am trying to connect `php` backend using `angular` client through `websocket`.
I am trying with `WebSocketSubject` from `rxjs`, but somehow I am not able to make a connection.

This code is not working

```
this.socket$ = WebSocketSubject.create('ws://localhost:12345/websockets.php');

this.socket$
   .subscribe(
       (message) => { 
             console.log(message);
        },
       (err) => console.error(err)
);
```

*I do not get any errors on the console as well.*

I have tested with ES6 `WebSocket`, which just works fine. So no issue with the server. It responds well.

This code works :

```
var host = 'ws://localhost:12345/websockets.php';
var socket = new WebSocket(host);
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data)
};
```

Can someone please point me out, what am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it give errors that you see in the dev tools ?

Comment: No errors at all. That would have helped me at least.

Comment: Do you see the websocket being created?

Comment: @Jacopofar No, it is not making any connection. I tried logging inside the server code.

Answer (score 2):

The rxjs interface has changed slightly. Where you instantiate the `WebSocketSubject` change:

```
this.webSocketSubject = WebSocketSubject.create(...);
```

to:

```
this.webSocketSubject = new WebSocketSubject(...);
```

And where you are sending messages to the server change:

```
this.webSocketSubject.next(JSON.stringify(request));
```

to:

```
this.webSocketSubject.next(request);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess it has few more issues in parsing. Because the response that I get from server always invokes `error` block of `subscribe`. I get `Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0`. Some internal parsing is happening, not sure what it is.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Did you remove the `JSON.stringify` on the client side?

Comment: I am not sending any message from the client side. I am only receiving it from the server.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Check the contents of the message from the server side (in developer tools/network/localhost) to see that your message from the server is valid JSON, for example, `{clientId: 209, messageType: "LoginResp", requestId: 6}`.

Comment: I am actually sending a string buffer not a JSON object. My server code is in php. I am doint it using `socket_write` http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php

Comment: WebSocketSubject is expecting a JSON string in the message.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an observable with the method: `fromEvent`, this can be imported from rxjs.

**1. Create websocket**

Create a new WebSocket('withyoururl'):

`const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:12345/websockets.php');`

[Websocket documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

**2. Set your event listeners**

For example, send your authentication upon onopen.

`websocket.onopen = (event) => { websocket.send(JSON.stringify({'jwt': 'blaat'})) }`

[Listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Properties)

**3. Create observable from event**

You can create observables from events, this event will be received once you subscribe to it.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const observable$ = fromEvent(websocket, 'message'); // Receives message events once you subscribe to this observable.
```

[Creation of observable from an event](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html)

Comment: I know this method works which I have mentioned in my question as well. But any idea why it is not working with `WebSocketSubject`?

Answer (score 1):

To create a stream based on websockets you can use the `websocket` function(!):

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';     

this.socket$ = websocket('ws://localhost:12345/websockets.php');

this.socket$
  .subscribe(
     (message) => { 
           console.log(message);
      },
     (err) => console.error(err)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and let you know. This method should work I guess. But still not sure what is the issue with `webSocketSubject`.

Comment: It seems like, it is making a connection now, but not getting the data from the server instead  error callback is executed. It prints `Event {isTrusted: true}
isTrusted: true
__proto__: Event`